# How to create a pdf from two UIViews with 2 pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiview

I have two `UIView`s that needs to be converted to a PDF and send as an attachment. My code below overlaps the first `UIView`.
I would like to send this as an attachment to an email.

Thank you.

```
NSMutableData *pdfData=[NSMutableData data];


UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData,aView.bounds, nil);
CGContextRef pdfContext=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
 UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();


UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, bView.bounds, nil);

CGContextRef pdfContext2=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

[bView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext2];
  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();



MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSString *subject=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delivery Report-%@",[globUserID uppercaseString]];
[mailer setSubject:subject];
[mailer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"pdf" fileName:@"DeliveryReport.pdf"];
[self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't create a second context.

```
NSMutableData *pdfData=[NSMutableData data];
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792); // letter sized paper, adjust as needed

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, bounds, nil);
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[bView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Comment: thank you very much that works, any tips if i want to make the first page potrait the second page landscape?

Comment: Use the `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo` function to start a new page with different dimensions.

Comment: like this? 'NSMutableData *pdfData=[NSMutableData data];
    CGRect bounds1=aView.bounds;
     CGRect bounds2=bView.bounds;
    
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData,bounds1, nil);
    CGContextRef pdfContext=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData,bounds2, nil);
   UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    [bView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

      UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();'

Comment: No. In my answer, replace calls to `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage` with calls to `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo` passing in the size for the page.

Comment: Tannk you.. you saved lot of time